# Knockout mapping to a child object

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm trying to map JSON data to a child object, I can get it to work using the root object:

`var data = {transfer: {"VisitTransferId":"a46bb9ce-9feb-410b-b643-d917560bb6e5","FromVisit":"16*15997*2*2","ToVisit":"10*1*9*9*9"}};`
`ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, visitDetailsVm);`

like in this JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dcanning/z8u9g/), but I'd like to know why it doesn't work when specifying the child object  when doing the mapping (the data is not the same between these two):

`var data = {"VisitTransferId":"a46bb9ce-9feb-410b-b643-d917560bb6e5","FromVisit":"16*15997*2*2","ToVisit":"10*1*9*9*9"};`
`ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, visitDetailsVm.transfer);`

like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dcanning/BWgwt/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run mapping and provide the variable to receive the data, you're actually setting the value of a variable...not filling the observable. So you're overriding the observable entirely.

Check out http://jsfiddle.net/BWgwt/3/

```
        var visitDetailsVm = new VisitDetails();
        visitDetailsVm.transfer(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));

        var mappedAmas = ko.utils.arrayMap(amadata, function(ama) {
            return ko.mapping.fromJS(ama);
        });
        visitDetailsVm.amas(mappedAmas);
```

With the observable array, you'd actually want to map each of the instances in your data array then fill your observable array with the mapped results.

Comment: So my question is then why is the obserable array I created for the amas not overwritten and broken like the transfer?  I can see this is the answer but I want to understand what is going on (preferably without having to dig through the source for ko.mapping)

Comment: My question would be...what do you want to be observable? The collection or the properties of each object in the collection or both? The mapping plugin is meant to take an object and make its properties observable so you don't have to declare them manually.

Comment: That would be the properties on each object in the collection.

Comment: In that case, you'd need to first map each object as is done for 'mappedAmas'. If you don't need that collection to be observed, no need to stuff it back into an observableArray.